# Why are all Slim routes being initialized on load/start?

Tags: php, rest, slim

Ok, to me this one is rather odd. But I'm probably just missing something.

I have a REST API using Slim with about 20 routes. Each route loads a MySQL class with a db config passed to the construct.

But, any time I'm adding a new route with a new db connection config (that I havent yet setup in the db), it throws a "bad db config" exception even though I am not calling the new/unfinished route.

So, it seems that the MySQL class in EVERY ROUTE is being instantiated whenever I make an API call.

Ummm..?

CODE SAMPLE PER REQUEST:

```
$app->group('/content/get', function () use ($app) {

require('config/mysql.settings.php');
$db = new MySQL($dbconfig['pages']);

  $app->get('/:site/:page', function ($site, $page)  use ($app, $db) {
    ...
  });


});     

$app->group('/library/get', function () use ($app) {

require('config/mysql.settings.php');
$db = new MySQL($dbconfig['docs']);

  $app->get('/:doc', function ($doc)  use ($app, $db) {
    ...
  });

});     

$app->group('/price/get', function () use ($app) {

require('config/mysql.settings.php');
$db = new MySQL($dbconfig['price']);

  $app->get('/:doc', function ($doc)  use ($app, $db) {
    ...
  });

});
```

If the user for the "price" configuration hasnt been added to the db, and I make a call to /library/get, I get a db error. Once I add the price user to the db, the error stops.

It has done this with every new db user I specify in a route - until its actually added to the db.

Comment: Haven't used Slim, so I can't comment there. But it may be worth initializing the database connection in a separate class that can be called when needed (and will not be recreated if it already exists).

Comment: That does sound odd. Can you please provide a code sample showing a couple of your routes?

Comment: @JeremyKendall : code sample added

Comment: @Akkh I think I know what's going on, but I want to write a test before I guess. Could you share the MySQL constructor in the meantime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The Problem

This is a PHP thing, not a Slim thing.  We both know that a PHP script executes from top to bottom, acting upon and evaluating whatever it finds as it goes.  While it's true that code within Slim routes isn't executed until a route is matched, your MySQL class instantiation is happening within a route group definition, *not* within a route.

## An Example

This example, based on the [Slim Skeleton](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Skeleton), is what I worked up to verify what I figured was happening.

```
<?php

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

// Prepare app
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

var_dump('app');

// Define routes
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    echo "/";
});

$app->group('/v1', function () use ($app) {

    var_dump('/v1/var_dump');

    $app->get('/home', function () use ($app) {
        echo "/v1/home";
    });
});

$app->group('/v2', function () use ($app) {

    var_dump('/v2/var_dump');

    $app->get('/home', function () use ($app) {
        echo "/v2/home";
    });
});

// Run app
$app->run();
```

No matter which route you hit, all three calls to `var_dump` will be executed before the route code is executed.

## A Recommendation

If this were my app, I'd consider using Slim's [resource locator](http://docs.slimframework.com/#DI-Overview) to configure your DB connections.

```
$app->dbConfig = $dbconfig;
$app->docsDb = function () use ($app) {
    return new MySQL($app->dbconfig['docs']);
};
```

Then, within the appropriate route, you can use the connection like so (assuming you have a `findAll()` method on your `MySQL` class):

```
$app->get('/example', function () use ($app) {
    $allDocs = $app->docsDb->findAll(); 
});
```

There are myriad benefits to that, not the least of which is avoiding having code in your `index.php` that's being unexpectedly executed out of turn.

Comment: Wow. Ok. You just made my head hurt. hehe. As for the PHP execution, I just ASSumed the groups/routes basically acted like functions/methods and as such, nothing inside would execute unless that "function" was called. I guess I was wrong there. Thanks! As for the resource location, I'm confused. I need to specify the dbconfig (its just an MD array with the connection strings assigned via the keys) based on each route group.

Comment: And, I use the instance of the MySQL class ($db) inside other classes that actually do the work by passing $db to the constructors like:     function __construct($db) {

  $this->dbclass = $db;

    } with no $db calls actually being made via the "index". So I dont understand how that could work. Am I doing it all wrong? :0

Comment: I'm guessing that I could just pass $app->docsDB to the other classes constructors, but still dont understand how I can assign the db config at the group level with your example. Are you saying I should have one of the "new MySQL" functions for each of the db configs before all the groups/routes and then call whichever function I need within the groups/functions? Im sorry if Im slow.

Comment: You're not slow at all.  I had a hard time getting the hang of DI, but it made all the difference when I got it sorted out.  Yes, I would have a new `MySQL` class per route group (per your requirements).  You can set the entire config array as a property on `$app` and access it as needed within your routes.

Comment: If you want to talk more about DI and/or application architecture, get in touch with me via my website in my profile.

Comment: @JeremyKendall Thank you Jeremy this was really useful. I also just downloaded your plugin from Github : Slim-Auth but I am having issues with the PDO driver it throws exceptions that the driver was not found.. I should come back and post a question over here. Thanks for sharing your work. You have my respect!